# Shell script to update DB via flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I got started with [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#quickstart) and I tried out the [Flaskr](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/flaskr/) example. On the execution of a certain python script, I would like to update one row of my database.

I am a newbie here and would like to understand: am I going to update the DB from inside that python script or I am going to wait for a signal from the flask WSGI script:
I have referred to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292612/flask-sqlalchemy-how-to-update-insert-row-in-db) but am not sure how I am going to interact with the external script. Any help or hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSGI handles HTTP requests/responses.  A script won't be issuing those.  Instead, import your Flask app in the script and make an application context:

```
from my_project import my_app

ctx = my_app.app_context()
ctx.push()

# ... my code

db.session.commit()

ctx.pop()
```

Relevant docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/appcontext/, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/shell/

Or consider using [Flask-Script](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to add command line functions to your application, if the function doesn't need to be a separate script.